# Is Normalization in Database still useful?

Tags: database

since we know that memory now has become very cheap and acquires very less space.Is there any use of normalization in database? i.e., even if redundancy occurs then there is not much problem as we have abundant memory now a days. simply wasting time on normalization will cost..io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! normalization does more than just reduce redundancy. A normalized database is much more flexible and much easier to modify down the road. Database design is very important and optimization/normalization shouldn't be discounted simply because resources are readily available. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Minimize_redesign_when_extending_the_database_structure) actually has a nice little piece on this.

Answer (score 1):

Although memory is cheap, the use of a normalizer means it stores data in more optimal way and it doesn't have hassle from update errors and deleting anomalies. That being said, memory in a database is definitely the best way to go.